# Any way to make Postgres stricter when creating functions?

Tags: postgresql

We started to use Postgres much more recently, having moved from SQL Server. I've noticed that Postgres parser/compiler allows creation of functions that (it seems to me) can be rejected at creation time.

One example of what I'm talking about is select statements in plpgsql blocks:

```
create or replace function test() returns void as $$
begin
    select * from pg_database;
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This function fails at runtime with ***"query has no destination for result data"***. Why would this error not be caught at function creation time? Is there any case when using select without 'return' in plpgsql block is allowed?

The other type of errors that are not always caught at compile time is type mismatch errors between a declared return type and actual type of the value. These are caught in simple cases, but start to make it to runtime in more complicated functions. I suspect there's some limitations in Postgres type inference/analysis, is there any additional information on this available?

tldr: Is there any way to make Postgres parser/compiler fail more on function creation?

Comment: I always include a commented test section in every function. The practical difference, between having the create function fail as opposed to it succeeding and then the test fail, is therefore slight. Even in complex functions, the error messaging on test fail is very accurate as to the cause. As a result, this shortcoming of PostgreSQL never bothers me very much.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is one of the possible ways out of it - we're considering writing some kind of test suite that would call each function one with some random parameters. Still, seems like quite a lot of work for something that could've been done automatically.

Comment: That testing needs to be done anyway. So it is **zero** additional work.

Comment: It's not zero additional work, no. There's advantages of having compiler doing these checks this for you, just like in case with statically typed languages. You can catch this with tests, but it's trickier (see my example where a simple test on empty tables is not good enough), and it's much easier to accidentally commit incorrect code.

Comment: "*I suspect there's some limitations in Postgres type inference*" - I think the limitation is that the types of the referenced columns (or even whole relations) could change between function invocations.

Comment: @Bergi - It can't be only what you say, because if you do something very simple and wrong, Postgres will complain! For example, the following code fails at compile time.
create table testtbl(num int);
create function testfun() returns testtbl as $$
    select 'string';
    $$ language sql;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there any way to make Postgres parser/compiler fail more on function creation?*

That's the purpose of the [`plpgsql_check`](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check) extension. It won't prevent the function to be created, though.

```
test=# create extension plpgsql_check;
CREATE EXTENSION

test=# create or replace function test() returns void as $$
begin
    select * from pg_database;
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;

test=# select * from plpgsql_check_function('test');
                        plpgsql_check_function                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 error:42601:3:SQL statement:query has no destination for result data
```

Comment: Nice. Could this work with functions receiving parameters?